# discord bot throwing RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

created this python script for a discord bot, its supposed to pull the public IP for my MC server and post it to a channel in our group discord.

it keeps throwing the error in the title and i cant tell why

```
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

# Replace 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE' with your actual bot token.
TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

# Enable the default intents for the bot
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False  # Disable typing events if you don't need them
intents.presences = False  # Disable presence events if you don't need them

# Function to get the IP address using an external service
def get_ip():
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()['ip']
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Failed to fetch IP address: {e}")
    return None

# Load and save the channel ID in a file (you can use a database for more advanced bots)
def load_channel_id():
    try:
        with open('channel_id.txt', 'r') as file:
            return int(file.readline())
    except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError):
        return None

def save_channel_id(channel_id):
    with open('channel_id.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(channel_id))

# Create a bot instance with the desired command prefix and name
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='IPBot', intents=intents)

# Function to post the IP address in a comment every 12 hours
@tasks.loop(hours=12)
async def post_ip():
    channel_id = load_channel_id()
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    if channel:
        ip_address = get_ip()
        if ip_address:
            # Check if there's an existing message from the bot
            async for message in channel.history():
                if message.author == bot.user:
                    await message.delete()
                    break

            # Post the new IP address
            new_message = await channel.send(f'Your IP address is: {ip_address}')

            # Pin the new message
            await new_message.pin()
        else:
            await channel.send('Failed to retrieve IP address.')

# Command: !set_channel_id
@bot.command()
async def set_channel_id(ctx, channel_id: int):
    if not ctx.guild:
        return await ctx.send("This command can only be used in a server (guild).")

    try:
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        if not channel:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.send("Invalid channel ID. Please provide a valid channel ID from this server.")
    
    save_channel_id(channel_id)
    await ctx.send(f'This channel (ID: {channel_id}) set as the destination for IPBot.')

# Command: !update_ip
@bot.command()
async def update_ip(ctx):
    channel_id = load_channel_id()
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    if channel:
        ip_address = get_ip()
        if ip_address:
            # Check if there's an existing message from the bot
            async for message in channel.history():
                if message.author == bot.user:
                    await message.delete()
                    break

            # Post the new IP address
            new_message = await channel.send(f'Your updated IP address is: {ip_address}')

            # Pin the new message
            await new_message.pin()
        else:
            await channel.send('Failed to retrieve updated IP address.')

# Event: Bot is ready and connected to Discord.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="!help for commands")) # Setting the bot's activity status
    post_ip.start()

# Run the bot with the specified token.
bot.run(TOKEN)`
```

originally was using client.run('[token]')

then bot.run('[token]')

then ChatGPT suggested that i put the TOKEN = line at the top and do it this way. im always getting the same error though.

Answer (score -1):

first, please know that what chatGPT has told you to do was just to use a constant value, since the token won't change. secondly, the error is not withim discord, it's because of your code. discord uses AsyncIO in order to run your code, so your code should follow asyncIO's rules and documentation as well, even if it is wrapped by discord's api.

in this case, Asyncio can only use run() outside of an event loop. i'm too lazy to run your code, since it would require me to setup a new discord bot, but i'm assuming you need to use the post_ip() function diffrently, such as using await instead of post_ip.start(), or maybe just search in Asyncio's docs.

however, i would instead suggest to remove @tasks.loop(hours=12) and instead use a while loop. like this:

```py
async def post_ip():
    while True:
        channel_id = load_channel_id()
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        if channel:
            ip_address = get_ip()
            if ip_address:
                # Check if there's an existing message from the bot
                async for message in channel.history():
                    if message.author == bot.user:
                        await message.delete()
                        break

                # Post the new IP address
                new_message = await channel.send(f'Your IP address is: {ip_address}')

                # Pin the new message
                await new_message.pin()
            else:
                await channel.send('Failed to retrieve IP address.')
```

i think that by using 12 hours, you actually want it to be infinite, which is why i am using `while True`, but if you actually want to use it for specificly 12 hours, use the time module (from the std library) in order to check the time after every function, and then check if the time that had passed is 12 hours.